# How can I lazily read Pytables HDF5s with a where clause into Dask?

Tags: dask, pytables

I have data stored in HDF5 files created by `pytables`.  I need to read these files using `read_where()` because I need to apply some filter criteria.

I see this tidy `h5py` [example](https://dask.pydata.org/en/doc-test-build/array-overview.html) in the `dask` docs:

```
dsets = [h5py.File(fn)['/data'] for fn in sorted(glob('myfiles.*.hdf5')]
arrays = [da.from_array(dset, chunks=(1000, 1000)) for dset in dsets]
```

Ordinarily, I'd be able to do something like this with `pytables` instead of `h5py`:

```
dsets = [tables.File(fn).root.data for fn in sorted(glob('myfiles.*.hdf5')]
```

However, I can't find a way in `pytables` to return a table-like result to `dask` with my filter applied that can be read lazily.  `read_where()` reads the entire array into memory, so I can't do this since my data is larger than memory:

```
dsets = [tables.File(fn).root.data.read_where('color == "blue"') for fn in sorted(glob('myfiles.*.hdf5')]
```

Is there a way around this in `pytables`?  Else, is there a way to wrap my read function in a generator like this and have dask use that to create the array?

```
def array_generator():
    for fn in sorted(glob('myfiles.*.hdf5'):
        yield tables.File(fn).root.data.read_where('color == "blue"')
```

Comment: Are you reading tabular data here, i.e., you want to produce a data-frame as opposed to an array?

Comment: @mdurant It's a numpy structured array, not a dataframe.  (I suspect this might be possible with dask delayed.)